# Output as pairs from a for loop

Tags: php

I've got an array. Below is an example

```
$arr = ["apple", "mango", "chair", "table", "pink", "red"];
```

I need to access 2 at a time within a for loop.

```
for ($i=0;$i<$arr.length;$i++){
   $var = 'First item is '.$arr[$i].' and the second is '.$arr[$i+1];
}
```

The 1st output is `First item is apple and the second is mango`.

But from the 2nd output is `First item is mango and the second is chair`.

I want to output in pairs. So the expected outputs are:

`First item is apple and the second is mango`

`First item is chair and the second is table`

`First item is pink and the second is red`

how do I do this? And I want to add a `<br>` tag at the end of each line except for the last.

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {
    echo "First item is {$arr[$i]} and the second is {$arr[$i + 1]} <br>";
}`

Comment: @Uchiha thanks. But I think the `<br>` is incorrect.

Comment: And why do you think its incorrect

Comment: @Uchiha The final line will have a `<br>`

Comment: It all depends on you how do you need an output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3rd parameter of for loop is `increment counter` (counter modifier) so you can change that to make your loop work the way you want. you can put any expression there which will evaluate for the next run

```
for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i=$i+2){
   $var = 'First item is '.$arr[$i].' and the second is '.$arr[$i+1];
   $var .= ($i == $len-1) ? '' : '<BR>';
 }
```

Comment: @Becky you can use a if condition, Updated answer. (may be there is a better way)